# I want to make an AJAX in my index.html to an endpoint of React, but I'm getting a homepage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

I want to make an `AJAX` call in `index.html` static file to an endpoint of `React`, but I'm getting a `React homepage`.

this is my Code in `index.html`:

```
<div id="data"></div>
<script>
        const doPostAjax = ()=>{
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/about",
                type: "get",
                success: function(res){
                    $("#data").html(res)
                }
            })
        }
</script>
```

how can I get the http://localhost:3000/about instate http://localhost:3000 as response?

Comment: Do you use [Server Side Rendering](https://www.bairesdev.com/blog/server-side-rendering-react/) using e.g. Next.js or Express.js? I believe that would be a minimal requirement for this to work. And even then you might run into issues, like React simply not being able to function after the initial load.

Comment: @PeterB I trying with nodes Backend, and rendering index.html static file

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

with `<iframe>` it is works:

`<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/about">`